# D0, D1, D2... DN branes consist of D0 branes?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, branes, matrix-model

In BFSS Matrix theory, D0-branes connect the ends of open strings. Do other D-branes (D1, D2... DN) consist of D0-branes?

Comment: The answer is yes. See chapter 5 in [Introduction to M theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9811019)

Comment: @RamiroHum-Sah Are D0-branes excitations of quantum fields, or are they separate objects that constantly and continuously interact with each other?